# Pass data from nodejs api to ts file ionic

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ionic-framework

If my api response is:
[{"**Customer_ID**":**1**}]

How can I get this **1** in my ts file without having to put it in an HTML file first?

I tried this way but it doesn't work/

api service

```
getUserIDByUsername(username):Observable<Customer>{
    return this.http
    .get<Customer>(this.api_URL +"/customers/" + username)
  }
```

customer class

```
export class Customer{
    Customer_ID :any;
}
```

.ts file

```
this.api.getUserDetailByUsername(this.username).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      this.userDetail = res.Customer_ID;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need `this.userDetail = res[0].Customer_ID;` (since the response is an array with a single element)

Comment: @ChrisG thanks a lot it worked!